# Python gives a segmentation fault if ran under a debugger - how to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pycharm

I have some Python code that calls a C extension I have written. When run through Python, this C code produces a segmentation fault, and so I'm trying to run it with PyCharm's debugger attached.

However, as soon as the Python program starts with the debugger attached, it immediately throws a segmentation fault. Note that normally, without the debugger, it runs through the majority of the code before it encounters the error - it doesn't error straight away like it does with the debugger attached.

Any ideas as to why this might be? I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post some relevant code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Could be code executed at `import` time.  When run through a debugger the code layout in memory changes, you can't expect consistent undefined behaviour.  A duff pointer, for example, can cause all kinds of undefined behaviour.